# Equation governing relative motion between aircraft and store

Tags: applied-mechanics, dynamics

I am reading a paper titled *Conditions for safe separation of external stores* by EE Covert [[Link]](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.44728?journalCode=ja). In Section 1 *Introduction* of the paper, the author has given an expression for $d$, the relative distance between some point $r_{p}$ on the store and $r_{q}$ on the aircraft as:

$$d = d \left( 0 \right) + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \left\{ \left[ R \right] \cdot \left( U + \omega \times r_{p}\right) - \left( V_{A/C} + \Omega \times r_{q} \right)\right\} \mathrm{d}t $$

where,

1. $ V_{A/C} $: aircraft translational velocity in aircraft body coordinates.
2. $ \Omega $: aircraft rotational velocity in aircraft body coordinates.
3. $ r_{q} $: position vector between aircraft center of gravity, and point of interest in aircraft.
4. $ r_{p} $: position vector between origin and point on store.
5. $ \left[ R \right] $: rotation matrix to transfer store velocities to aircraft coordinate frame.
6. $ U $: store linear velocity in store coordinates.
7. $ \omega $: store angular velocity in store coordinates.

I want to derive this expression, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive these EOM, you have to understand that there are two coordinate systems defined here, namely the store coordinate system ($X,Y,Z$) and the aircraft coordinate system ($X',Y',Z'$). Suppose the store has a linear velocity $U$ in its coordinate system, meaning $U := U_x\hat{i}' + U_y\hat{j}' + U_z\hat{k}'$. In the *aircraft* coordinate system, the velocity will be different, because the aircraft is translating and rotating as well. In general, the velocity at a point $Q$ in some reference frame, given the velocity at point $P$ is given by

$$
\vec{v}^Q = \vec{v}^P + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}^P,
$$
where $\omega$ denotes the angular velocity of that reference frame. This just comes from regular dynamics. Applied to this problem, the velocity of the origin (see Figure 1 in the paper) given the velocity of the store is

$$
U_0 = U + \omega\times r_p
$$
However, this is still in the reference frame of the *store*. In order toconvert this to the reference frame of the aircraft, you have to change reference frames. To do this, you have to multiple by the *direction cosine matrix* $R := R_{A/S}$, which rotates the store frame to the aircraft frame, so in total we get

$$
^AU_0 = R \ ^SU_0 = R(U + \omega\times r_p).
$$
This is just the first term in the equation in the paper, because it *only* considers the velocity of the store. However, the aircraft is moving too! So, you apply the same procedure to get the second term, except you have to add in a negative sign. This gives you the full equation that you are trying to understand.